# How to use variables in 'sed' command?

Tags: bash

Tried with following code:

```
revision=(revision="5.0")

sed -i "s/revision="1.0"/${revision}/g" /File-path/composite.xml)
```

But In the file the contents of revision="1.0" is replaced by ${revision}

Comment: The symptom you're describing is not consistent with your command; the symptom suggests that you used _single_ quotes around the `sed` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to quote: `"`

`sed -i "s/revision=\"1.0\"/${revision}/g" /File-path/composite.xml`

Comment: `But In the file the contents of revision="1.0" is replaced by ${revision}`, he made typo in his question.

Answer (score 0):

### Some syntax errors:

- `-i` switch tell [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) to execute *infile replacement*.
- `(...)` tell [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to store an array of variables.
- *leading `)`* seem wrong.

My purpose:

```
revision='revision="5.0"'

sed -e "s/revision=\"[0-9.]*\"/${revision}/g" /File-path/composite.xml
```

or if you want file `/File-path/composite.xml` to be modified:

```
sed -e "s/revision=\"[0-9.]*\"/${revision}/g" -i /File-path/composite.xml
```

or even:

```
sed -e "s/revision=\"[0-9.]*\"/${revision}/g" -i.bak /File-path/composite.xml
```